# Do custom attribute classes inherit the "Inherited" AttributeUsage flag?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Consider the following scenario:

- A base attribute class `BaseAttribute` has an `AttributeUsageAttribute` specifying that it is not inheritable (`Inherited = False`).
- A derived attribute class `DerivedAttribute` inherits from that base attribute class.
- A base domain class `Base` has the derived attribute applied.
- A domain class `Derived` inheriting from the base domain class is asked for its custom 
  attributes, including inherited attributes (`inherit: true`).

Here is the corresponding code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication26
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main ()
    {
      var attributes = typeof (Derived).GetCustomAttributes (true);
      foreach (var attribute in attributes)
      {
        Console.WriteLine (
            "{0}: Inherited = {1}",
            attribute.GetType().Name,
            attribute.GetType().GetCustomAttributes (typeof (AttributeUsageAttribute), true).Cast<AttributeUsageAttribute>().Single().Inherited);
      }
    }
  }

  [AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false)]
  public class BaseAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }

  public class DerivedAttribute : BaseAttribute
  {
  }

  [Derived]
  public class Base
  {
  }

  public class Derived : Base
  {
  }
}
```

In this scenario, the `GetCustomAttributes` API returns an instance of the `DerivedAttribute` class. I would have expected it to not return that instance because http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.aspx says that the `AttributeUsageAttribute` is itself inheritable.

Now, is this a bug, or is it to be expected/documented somewhere?

**Note (2013-02-20):** Experiments show that the `AttributeTargets` part of the `BaseAttribute` class is indeed inherited by the `DerivedAttribute` class. E.g., when I change the allowed targets on `BaseAttribute` to `AttributeTargets.Method`, the C# compiler won't allow me to apply `DerivedAttribute` to a class. Therefore, it doesn't make sense that the `Inherited = false` part is not inherited by `DerivedAttribute`, and I'm thus inclined to think of a bug in the implementation of `GetCustomAttributes`.

Comment: Not sure I see the issue.  If you don't want to see the attribute then you'll have to pass *false* to the GetCustomAttributes() method.

Comment: Yes, I know that I could just pass `false`. However, I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the attrigute when passing `true` even though the `Derived` class should not inherit the attribute. I'd like to be pointed to some piece of documentation or specification explaining what I'm seeing.

Comment: It does appear that the AttributeUsageAttribute Inherited flag is not inherited although one would expect it to be as the AttributeUsageAttribute is decorated with  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)].

Comment: We're experiencing a similar case with the AuthorizeAttribute.  We have several controllers that inherit from each other have increasingly restrictive permissions from an attribute called 'OurAuthorizeAttribute'.  When we don't explicitly add the AttributeUsage that is on the AuthorizeAttribute to our custom attribute, AuthorizeCore() doesn't stack.  When we add it, it behaves as expected.  'As expected' in our case is simply that attributes inherit their base attributeusage. We have unit tests against this behavior that we'll try to post. The AttributeUsage.Inherited property is disregarded.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, metadata for class **Derived** is constructed. The compiler checks the inheritance chain to see if any attributes need to be inherited. There it finds attribute **DerivedAttribute**. (I don't know if the attributes on **Object** are considered, but they are set to be not inherited anyway.) To see if it must be inherited, it checks for the **AttributeUsageAttribute** on the discovered attribute class. It does not have one of it's own; [the language specification states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#2222-attribute-usage):

> An attribute class **X** not having an **AttributeUsage** attribute attached to it, as in

```
class X : Attribute { ... }
```

> is equivalent to the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.All,
    AllowMultiple = false,
    Inherited = true)
]
class X : Attribute { ... }
```

My guess is that the compiler behaves this way and creates metadata which indicates that class **Derived** inherits custom attribute **DerivedAttribute**.

Then, at runtime, when getting custom attributes for class **Derived**, the class-ineritance chain is followed from class **Derived** to class **Base**, where a **DerivedAttribute** is found. Upon inspection, it can be seen that class **DerivedAttribute** has no **AttributeUsageAttribute** of it's own, but since **AttributeUsageAttribute** can be inherited, it inherits one from a parent.

During runtime the inheritance is performed as expected and the **AttributeUsageAttribute** of **BaseAttribute** is inherited, which has **Inherited** set to false.

I elongated the inheritance chain to check if the inherited attribute is that of the closest parent and not that of the root:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        var attributes = typeof (Level4Class).GetCustomAttributes (true);
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (
                "{0}: Inherited = {1}; ClassLevel = {2}",
                attribute.GetType().Name,
                attribute.GetType().GetCustomAttributes (typeof (AttributeUsageAttribute), true).Cast<AttributeUsageAttribute>().Single().Inherited,
                ((Level1Attribute)attribute).ClassLevel);
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class Level1Attribute : Attribute
{
    public int ClassLevel { get; set; }
}

public class Level2Attribute : Level1Attribute
{
}

public class Level3Attribute : Level2Attribute
{
}

[Level1(ClassLevel=1)]
[Level2(ClassLevel=1)]
[Level3(ClassLevel=1)]
public class Level1Class
{
}

[Level1(ClassLevel=2)]
[Level2(ClassLevel=2)]
[Level3(ClassLevel=2)]
public class Level2Class : Level1Class
{
}

public class Level3Class : Level2Class
{
}

public class Level4Class : Level3Class
{
}
```

Console output:

```
Level3Attribute: Inherited = False; ClassLevel = 2
Level2Attribute: Inherited = False; ClassLevel = 2
```

It seems that the compiler follows the language specification, but the runtime follows the coded definitions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the metadata in .NET 4.0, the `AttributeUsageAttribute` class is marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]`. So, If your attribute class (`BaseAttribute`, in your example), has an `AttributeUsageAttribute` applied to it (as all `Attribute` classes should, but don't break anything if they don't- see below), then any classes derrived from `BaseAttribute` should inherit that `AttributeUsage` attribute applied to it.

Your `Derived` class inherits `DerivedAttribute` from Base, because `DerivedAttribute` doesn't have its own `AttributeUsageAttribute` applied to it, so the reflection API relies on `BaseAttribute`'s attribute. Now, take the `AttributeUsageAttribute` off of your `BaseAttribute` class, and you get the same result, because the base `System.Attribute` class is marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]`. Thus, any attribute class will inherit this attribute, unless you specify a different one.

Wow, those are complicated paragraphs. Attributes on attributes makes for some heavy reading :P

Comment: But my `BaseAttribute` is declared to _not_ be inheritable. So, if the Reflection API relies on `BaseAttribute`'s declared attribute usage, why would the `DerivedAttribute` be inheritable?

Comment: Hm... Well, then... Good question!

Comment: Hey, I think you are confusing yourself with 'Inherited' here. AttributeUsage(AttributeUsageAttribute) itself is an attribute whose 'Inherited' is always true. When you are setting 'Inherited' in a custom Attribute written by you, you are essentially telling the runtime when your custom Attribute is applied to another class, should it too be applied to derived classes of that class.